# Issues with for loops in R

Tags: r

I am trying to combine some excel spreadsheets. There are 50 documents. I am looking to get sheets 2:5, except some only have sheets 2:3, 2:4, etc - this is why I include the try function. I need ranges F6:AZ2183 and I am transposing the data.

The **issue** I am running into is that only the last file is saving into the data frame df.

I attached the code below. If you have any ideas, I would much appreciate it!

Also, I'm a longtime lurker first time poster, so if my etiquette is poor, I apologize.

```
df <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:50){
  for (j in 2:5) {
    try({
      df.temp <- t(read_excel((paste0('FqReport',i,'.xlsx')), sheet = j, range ='F6:AZ2183'))
      df.temp <- df.temp[rowSums(is.na(df.temp)) != ncol(df.temp), ]
      df <- rbind(df, df.temp)
      rm(df.temp)
      gc()
    }, silent = TRUE)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can read the sheets available in each excel file which will avoid the use of `try`. Also growing dataframe in loop is quite inefficient. Try this `lapply` approach.

```
library(readxl)
filename <- paste0('FqReport',1:50,'.xlsx')

df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(filename, function(x) {
          sheet_name <- excel_sheets(x)[-1]
          do.call(rbind, lapply(sheet_name, function(y) {
                df.temp <- t(read_excel(x, y, range ='F6:AZ2183'))
                df.temp[rowSums(is.na(df.temp)) != ncol(df.temp), ]
          }))
      }))
```

Comment: This looks a lot simpler than what I was trying to do! Thank you. I am now getting an "Error: vector". Do you have any idea what may be causing this? I tried looking through but haven't found what's causing it yet.

Comment: What is the complete error message that you get? Do you have all these files in your working directory?

Comment: I do have all of the files in the working directory. The only error message that comes up is "Error: vector". I showed the traceback on it, and here is the last thing that it shows:

stop(structure(list(message = "vector", call = NULL, cppstack = NULL), class = c("std::out_of_range", 
"C++Error", "error", "condition")))

Comment: Can you resart R and try again? Are you able to read 1 file correctly with `read_excel` ? `read_excel(filename[1])` ?